# charAt method is returning an integer. Need to convert to int

Tags: java, char, int

I'm creating a method that will take the given input and set the value to "plate".  I then proceed to use the charAt method and try to take the characters(letters/String) input and set it to a new value. But i'm told to set it to a char value. When I run aprint statement with it, the output is just a bunch of integers, or in my case (for the code i'm going to show) it outputs "195" when I put the license plate as abc 123. Also, the model doesn't do anything(or atleast isnt supposed to). If anyone could tell me what exactly i'm doing wrong it would be a great help.

Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class CarRental {

```
public static String model;
public static String plate;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Car Model:");
    model = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("License Plate: ");
    plate = input.nextLine();

    char one = plate.charAt(0);
    char two = plate.charAt(1);

    System.out.println(two + one);

}
```

}

To make my issue clear, what I'm hoping to do is, assign the actual letters I type into the input to a separate value. I'm using the charAt method and it is returning integers.

if anyone could offer a suggestion it would help alot!

Thanks,
Sully

Comment: Could you paste some code, please?

Comment: I am very unclear with what you are asking. Could you possibly give some example inputs and their expected outputs?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I had to put it back in.

Comment: the `+` operator treats 2 chars as numbers, try `System.out.println("" + two + one);`

Comment: jlordo. thanks for the help! it worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `+` operator treats 2 chars as ints, try

```
System.out.println("" + two + one);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll accept the answer as soon as I can. I'm in school and it's over in 3 minutes. Will do it when i'm home! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can just use

```
Character.toChars(X)
```

Where x is your number to convert to char and then display said chars once they've been converted.